# In end-to-end encryption where should the asymmetric encryption keys be created?

Tags: javascript, python, end-to-end-encryption

I'm playing around with learning encryption with a mini messaging project, so far I can do symmetric encryption (AES) where everyone shares the same key, obviously not secure or ideal, I want to learn how to implement a true end-to-end encryption system. I've been told RSA is what I should use? My question is,

- Do I generate the keys completely on the client end in javascript, or is it ok to do the key generation on the server and give them to the client?
- Where do you store the private key in a website, is using sessions okay? Can I save the private key to localstorage?
- Is there a good walk through with examples of implementing something in JavaScript or Python? ie, Handling key exchanges, multiple users, etc

Comment: I have an E2E chat app, written in simple JS and PHP, fully open source and documented at https://github.com/rndme/nadachat . There's an included [security overview document](https://github.com/rndme/nadachat/blob/master/security.md) that explains the very steps you're asking about.

Comment: @dandavis awesome I'll take a look! cheers for that

Comment: @AriVictor please keep in mind that with crypto, not all code is created equal. Although dandavis should be commended for his exploration of e2e encryption and exeptional coding style, his code is not peer reviewed by researchers in the field and may contain problems that are not immediately evident

Comment: @Jenessa noted! this is all just a learning stage at the moment but i'll keep that in mind.

Comment: @dandavis the security overview document was extremely helpful, there isn't a lot of information online that breaks it down as simple as you did, definitely a resources I'm going to share with others!

Comment: @Jenessa: I agree with that 100%. Nadachat's based on years of experience (going back to the cryptocat days), months of research, and weeks of development. The encryption core (sjcl) is well-reviewed and popular. Do keep in mind though that audits are not foolproof: whatsapp had one, yet several vulnerabilities have been found since. 
Nadachat's the only web-based secure chat that's _fully_ open, front and back (afaik), and I would love an app audit (or three). In the meantime, any feedback is welcome and appreciated, thanks for speaking up.

Comment: @dandavis There are definitely a few issues with that code, though nothing serious (e.g. using PBKDF2 for an ECC-derived key). The lack of length padding for message ciphertext and precise timestamps also make various side-channel attacks easier. It should be reviewed by a professional cryptographer.

Comment: @forest: Thanks for looking, but i'm confused (not unheard of). Nadachat doesn't use PBKDF2.  The [message responses are chunked and padded](https://github.com/rndme/nadachat/blob/master/security.md#actual-conversation-record-6-messages-in-30-seconds) to the same block size, every server action is randomly delayed (`usleep(rand(103456, 170000));`), and the client decryption runs in it's own thread to frustrate side-channel attacks. If there are vulns, i want them fixed ASAP, but I don't quite understand how your comments apply to nadachat; elaboration would be very welcome. Thanks again!

Comment: @dandavis The JSON specifies an "iterations" field. It might be some other password-based KDF if not PBKDF2, but regardless, it's unnecessary. I think it's the cryptography library that you're using.

Comment: @forest sweet. There's no passwords used, so no KDFs. I used the base core lib from SJCL unaltered to allow easier comparisons/auditing and (hopefully) transferred trust, instead of making a custom package that would need complex manual verification to be sure i didn't screw something up. Thanks!

Comment: @dandavis I checked out your nadachat.com.  Very cool!  What are your thoughts on browser-based chat with persistent chats and/or persistent addresses?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In true end-to-end encryption you'd generate keys for authentication on the client. The actual encryption is usually done using an algorithm which supports forward secrecy, like Diffie-Hellman. The web is a bad form factor for this, as local storage can usually be deleted at any time.

As for your last question: there is an implementation of the Signal protocol in JS here: https://github.com/signalapp/libsignal-protocol-javascript